# How to define a feature spec for multi-output regression neural network?

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

According to [this Tensorflow tutorial](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/beginners/load/load_csv/) by *Rstudio* we can define a `spec` (to preprocess our `tensor` data) using:

```
library(keras)
library(tfdatasets)
spec <- feature_spec(train_dataset, y ~ .)
```

However, I am working on a multi-output regression problem (Multi-output Neural Network) with `Keras` which means I have more than one `y` or `response` variables. I tried to define the `spec` using:

```
spec <- feature_spec(train_dataset, c(y1, y2, y3, y4, y5) ~ .)
```

But this gives me an error:

```
Error in validate_formula_operators(formula[[i]]) : 
  unhandled formula operator: expected '+' or '-'; got 'c'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "does not work" _how_? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @mhovd please see the update

Comment: Try with `cbind()` instead of `c()`

Comment: @mhovd this is what I get when I use `cbind()`: `Error in validate_formula_operators(formula[[i]]) : 
  unhandled formula operator: expected '+' or '-'; got 'cbind'`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, multiple response variables are not currently supported by `feature_spec()` (https://github.com/rstudio/tfdatasets/issues/88).